# PJSIP and FreeRTOS

Tags: sip, voip, pic, pjsip, rtos

I have been investigating the use of the PJSIP SIP stack on a small micro-controller such as the PIC32 MCU and I've come to realise that it may just be possible. I want only the absolute minimal SIP functionality so I just might be able to fit PJSIP on a small MCU. Of course, it's a VERY ambitious project but I'm gonna give it a try anyway. I just can't seem to wrap my mind around the right operating system for use so I'm gonna spend a good couple weeks on this subject. I'm gonna take a look at FreeRTOS. Any thoughts on the compatibility of FreeRTOS with something like PJSIP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the project site itself answers your question:

- [On portability](http://www.pjsip.org/about.htm#portable)
- [On Size](http://www.pjsip.org/about.htm#compact)

The memory resources suggested would be at the upper end for most on-chip memory.  The RTOS's listed are all significantly more fully featured than FreeRTOS which provides little more than thread scheduling, timer services, synchronisation and IPC.  You'd need to understand what OS services it assumes.  Presumably it uses the platform's network stack?  FreeRTOS has no network stack - you'd have to provide that too - more resources again.

Comment: Thanks...good enough answer for me. I'm just gonna do more research. I figure a different MCU might be needed... let's see

Comment: @Clifford I know the question is old, but how about TI CC3200 ? It has network stack built in to special TIRTOS.

Comment: @Prasad : My answer was very generic and applies regardless of processor.  I just read the project documentation on footprint and portability.  I have never used the library personally.  My answer really boils down to read the documentation and perform your own evaluation.

Comment: @Clifford thanks for the response, Yeah i noticed above even before, I'm still doing my research. Lets see how it goes :)